# Passportjs not saving user into session after login

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, passport-local

I'm working on a simple social network and I want users to register and log in locally trough passport.js. I was following [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)tutorial and all code runs with no errors. However when I try to log in User passes the authentication but doesn't stay in session when I print `req.session` on index route. Here is my passport config file:

```
 var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../server/models/User.js');


module.exports = function(passport){
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
        console.log('Serialized');
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
        console.log('Deserialized');
        User.findOne({id:id}, function(err, user){
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField:'email',
        passwordField:'password',
        passReqToCallback:true
    },function(req, email, password, done){
        console.log('Started');
        User.findOne({email:email}, function(err, user){
            console.log('Find query');
            if(err){
                console.log('Error occured');
                console.error(err);
                return done(err);
            }
            console.log('No error');
            if(!user)return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user with this email found'));
            console.log('Got user', user);
            if(!user.validatePassword(password, user.password)){
                console.log('Not valid suka');
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong password!'));
            }
            console.log('Valid pass');
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
}
```

This is my server.js file:

```
  //Dependencies
const express = require('express');

const passport = require('passport');

const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const flash = require('connect-flash');

const path = require('path');

const morgan = require('morgan');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Mongo setup
var mongoPath = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/party-net';

mongoose.connect(mongoPath, function(){
    console.log('Party-net database connected');
});

//Passport
require('./config/passport.js')(passport);

//Application setup
var app = express();


//Static files
app.use('/views', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'views')));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'scripts')));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));

//Middleware setup
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({secret:'muchsecretinfomustkipithir', saveUninitialized:true, resave:true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

//Routes
const index = require('./server/routes/index.js')(app, passport);
const api = require('./server/routes/api.js')(app, passport);

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
});
```

Login route code:

```
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    failureRedirect:'/'
}), (req, res) => {
    console.log('Login route', req.isAuthenticated(), req.session);
    //res.sendStatus(200);
    res.redirect('/');
    //res.redirect('/'+req.user.name+'/'+req.user.lastname);
});
```

And finally index route code:

```
 app.get('/:firstname/:lastname', isLoggedIn , (req, res) => {
        console.log('Requested', req.user, req.isAuthenticated());
        res.send('Logged in successfully ' + req.params.firstname + ' ' + req.params.lastname);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably passport cannot deserialize user as you've used: `User.findOne({id: id}, ...` but serialized it by `user._id` so you should use:

```
User.findOne({ _id: id }, ...
```

or [findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) method:

```
User.findById(id, function(err, user) { ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

try this

app.use(session({
secret: "123",
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000}
}));

Comment: while answering, add some description about your solution to better understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility I ran into when authenticate with `passport-local` is the using `email` as the input name.

The correct body should have `username` and `password`