# angular2/4 cant find object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Why do i get cannot find `object`?

I get the following error :

```
core.service.ts (19,23): Cannot find name 'object'.
```

in line:

```
 userChange: Subject<object> = new Subject<object>();
```

i do have these imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable, } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Comment } from './models/comment'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { Router, NavigationEnd, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CoreService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) { }

   userChange: Subject<object> = new Subject<object>();


further...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant `Object` with a capital **O**. JavaScript / Typescript is case sensitive.

```
userChange: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<any>`.

```
userChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

Here you find the `any` [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any), in the example code you will see the difference between using `Object` and `any`.

I would approach your code this way *(personal preference)*:

```
userChange$: Observable<any>;  // We declare the Observable

private userChangeSubject = new Subject<any>();  // We declare the Subject

constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {
     this.userChange$ = this.userChangeSubject.asObservable();  // We 'associate' the Subject with the Observable
}

updateUser(someUserParams) {
        this.userChangeSubject.next(someUserParams); // We then proceed to apply our logic and anyone subscribe to 'userChange$' will receive these someUserParams when this method is triggered
}
```

Comment: thanks!. Im new to angular 2, but have done some projects before on angular1. Could we have a talk?

Comment: Do you have a channel for more discussion?

Comment: because of my 150 rep lost to another topic bounty i get the following: You need 20 reputation to post messages

Comment: @maria means that you need more reputation to chat. Anyway, if you have more trouble with your developing keep creating new questions in StackOverflow and we will help you. If you want, you can tag me so I can see the question and try to give you a hand. But Really don't hesitate on using SO's platform, is one of the quickest ways to learn your path through a new language/framework. ;)

Comment: I believe i tagged you know . tagged with [tag:SrAxi]

Comment: anyway, link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762374/session-passport-wont-save

Comment: With the new approatch here, how would i call it in the service?  this.CoreService.userchange$.subscribe((value) => {
   
    }); wont work.

Comment: Check this example about astronauts in Angular's documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service . Basically, you have **component1** calling the method in the shared service, in our case: `updateUser()`. **Component2** is listening with the above code you just commented, and receives the parameters or whatever `updateUser()` is returning.

Answer (score 0):

The `object` type was added in TypeScript 2.2, are you sure you're using the right TypeScript version?

For more info see: [What's-new-in-TypeScript#object-type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#object-type)